# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_brotli' when trying to install dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash, brotli

I try to install dash on a mac OS, and I have the following error when running 'import dash' on a python script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 16, in <module>
    import dash
  File "/Users/manuel/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/dash/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .dash import Dash, no_update  # noqa: F401,E402
  File "/Users/manuel/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 17, in <module>
    from flask_compress import Compress
  File "/Users/manuel/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask_compress/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .flask_compress import Compress
  File "/Users/manuel/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask_compress/flask_compress.py", line 14, in <module>
    import brotli
  File "/Users/manuel/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/brotli.py", line 8, in <module>
    import _brotli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_brotli'
```

I can't figure it out what is the problem. I use python 3.7. I saw on the internet a similar issue on windows, but not on mac. I would be really grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a broken installation of the `brotli` module (missing its native code component `_brotli`).

Try uninstalling it with `pip uninstall brotli`, then reinstall it; `pip install brotli`.

Going forward, I would heavily recommend you learn and use virtualenvs instead of installing everything into your Python's `site-packages`.

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling and installing again brotli it worked! Moreover, working in virtual environments is really more appropriate. Thank you a lot, AKX.