# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_brotli'

Tags: python, brotli

Encountered the following error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_brotli'

I already tried to uninstall/install brotli, however the error remains. I'm new to python so any support is much appreciated!

Using Anaconda on Windows

```
    import dash
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .dash import Dash, no_update  # noqa: F401,E402
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 17, in <module>
    from flask_compress import Compress
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_compress\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .flask_compress import Compress
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_compress\flask_compress.py", line 14, in <module>
    import brotli
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\brotli.py", line 8, in <module>
    import _brotli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_brotli'
```

Comment: Perhaps related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69362337/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-brotli-when-trying-to-install-dash

Comment: Please provide your environment, operating system, etc. Do you use anaconda?

Comment: Edited original post and included error message